# Tensorflow tf.layer.batch_normalization: how to use global moving stats to do normalization during training?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

From the documentation, the arg training

> Either a Python boolean, or a TensorFlow boolean scalar tensor (e.g. a placeholder). Whether to return the output in training mode (normalized with statistics of the current batch) or in inference mode (normalized with moving statistics). NOTE: make sure to set this parameter correctly, or else your training/inference will not work properly.

It never mentioned that this arg also controls whether to update global moving stats. Even if the update ops is added through

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, 'train_model') 
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_ops = ...
```

they will not be updated is `training=False`. I am curious if there is a way to have these moving stats keep updating during training, at the same time use them to perform normalization?